# problem in main xml

Tags: android

Unable to resolve drawable "@drawable/bg" in attribute "background"
Unable to resolve drawable "@drawable/banner_footer" in attribute "src"
Unable to resolve drawable "@drawable/round_border" in attribute "background"
Unable to resolve drawable "@drawable/selector_tweet_btn" in attribute "src"
Unable to resolve drawable "@drawable/selector_msg_btn" in attribute "src"
Unable to resolve drawable "@drawable/selector_fbshare_btn" in attribute "src"
Unable to resolve drawable "@drawable/title" in attribute "src"

Comment: just put all these files in drawable folder also make sure that all these files are in .PNG format

Answer (score 0):

just put all these files in drawable folder also make sure that all these files are in .PNG format

Answer (score 0):

hi deep you have to put the files banner_footer ,round _border  etc  in the drawable folder of your project folder.these all will be images .if you don have these means just rename other suitable images with this names and paste that images in drawable folder